# How to lowercase a specific word in a string php

Tags: php, preg-replace, lowercase

Hye Guys !!

I need your help !
Here are 2 elements:

```
$string = "Legend Of Zelda";
$array = array("to","of","at");
```

I'd like to check if $string contains one of the $array elements and lowercase it.
Tried this, but failed ... i got the felling that the first element of the preg_replace should be a pattern or so ?

```
echo preg_replace($array, mb_strtolower($array), $string);
```

Any idea ?
Thanks a lot from France !

Comment: Moreover, [mb_strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php) requires a `string` as parameter, not an array. [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)
 might help with errors

Comment: `foreach($array as $element) $string = str_ireplace($element, strtolower($element), $string);`. You simply can adopt to mb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$string = "Legend Of Zelda";
$array = array("to","of","at");
echo preg_replace_callback('~\b(?:' . implode("|", $array) . ')\b~ui', function ($m) {
    return mb_strtolower($m[0]);
  }, $string);
```

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/4oaeG).

The regex will look like `\b(?:to|of|at)\b` here, see [its demo online](https://regex101.com/r/7aWf0v/1).

The `/i` flag will ensure case insensitive search and `/u` will handle all Unicode chars correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you :

```
$content = "Legend Of Zelda";
$array = array("to","of","at");

foreach($array as $value)
{
    $pattern = '/'.$value.'/i';
    $content = preg_replace($pattern, strtolower($value) , $content);
}


echo $content;
```